# Method or data member not found in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone please help me out.? I am getting the compile error.
Thanks!

Written in a seperate module :

```
Sub Compare2Worksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
    Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
    Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
    Dim row As Long, col As Integer
    Set report = Workbooks.Add

    With ws1.UsedRange
        ws1row = Rows.Count
        ws1.col = Columns.Count
    End With

    With ws2.UsedRange
        ws2row = Rows.Count
        ws2col = Columns.Count
    End With

    maxrow = ws1row
    maxcol = ws1column

    If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
    If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

    difference = 0
    For col = 1 To maxcol
        For row = 1 To maxrow
            colval1 = ""
            colval2 = ""
            colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
            colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula

            If colval1 <> colval2 Then
                difference = difference + 1
                Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
                Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
                Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
                Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next row
    Next col
End
```

Written for a command button inserted

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set myWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\testsample.xlsm")
    Compare2Worksheets myWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1"), myWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet2")
End Sub
```

Please note that this a code that i got from a VBA basics tutorial.

Comment: What error, what line? Could you please EDIT your question and specify it a little bit more? Please avoid posting details in comments. Thanks

Comment: You probably get the compile error because there is `End` where it should be `End Sub`. Also your `With` statements are useless because you don't use them. Look into a tutorial how to use `With` correctly.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. End Sub was a copying mistake. the code worked now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change  `ws1.col = Columns.Count` to `ws1col = Columns.Count` to get rid of the first error. Guessing this was a typo for the variable name but the compiler is looking for a method or property called `col` due to the `"."`. See point 3.
2. Change this `ws1column` to `ws1col`
3. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to check for these sorts of things i.e. the mistakes above
4. Note that using syntax such as `Cells(row, col)` etc, where you don't specify the sheet name you are working with, will default to the `Activesheet`, which may or may not be the sheet you intended. This can lead to bugs. Better to specify explicitly which sheet you are working with and then use `.` syntax e.g.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(row, col)
End With
```

5. When using With statement, inside of the With, when referring to the parent object you use "." e.g.  `.Rows.Count`
6. I automatically corrected the `End` to `End Sub`, thinking I had made a mistake copying. Just noticed now, from comments, that this should also have been End Sub not `End`. `End` will terminate the programme.